# Big-O & Little-O Notation and Matrices

Tags: matrices, limits, asymptotics

I wonder how the Big Oh and Little Oh notation works while working with matrices. The [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) doesn't list any matrix results, and so do [the sources of this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1519347/arithmetic-rules-for-big-o-notation-little-o-notation-and-so-on?noredirect=1&lq=1).

As a remainder:

(D1) $a_n = O(b_n)$ if there exist a $M > 0$ and $N$ such that $|a_n/b_n| < M$ for $n > N$

(D2) $a_n = o(b_n)$ if for any $M > 0$, there exists a $N_M$ such that $|a_n/b_n| < M$ for $n > N$

Consider vector $v_n$ and $w_n$, sequences of matrices ${\bf A}_n$ and ${\bf B}_n$ and $||{\bf A}||$ the sup norm of ${ \bf A}$ and $|{\bf A}|$ the determinant. I assume them commutative as needed. Of course, there is the obvious,

(1) If $||{\bf A}_n|| = O(1),||{\bf B}_n|| = O(1)$  then $|| { \bf A } _n { \bf B }_n || = O(1)$

(2) If $||{\bf A}_n|| = O(1)$, $v_n = O(1)$, and $w_n = O(1)$, then $v_n{\bf A}_n w_n = O(1) $

Both (1) and (2) can be proved easily by taking the max over each element.

(3) [I also found out recently](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2800567/matrix-inverse-and-bounds?noredirect=1#comment5773861_2800567) that

If $||{\bf A}_n^{-1}|| = O(a_n)$, $a_n \to \infty$, and $||{\bf B}_n|| = o(1)$ , then $||[{ \bf A}_n + { \bf B}_n]^{-1}|| = O(a_n)$

(4) For semidefinite $k\times k$ matrices ${\bf A}_n$, $tr({\bf A}_n) = O(a_n)$ iff $\lambda_{n}^L = O(a_n)$ iff $||{\bf A}_n|| = O(a_n)$, with $\lambda_n^L$ the largest eigenvalue of ${\bf A}_n$. Also, these imply $|{\bf A}_n| = O(a_n^k)$ and, for [positive definite matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1832085/upper-and-lower-bounds-log-determinant), $log(|{\bf A}_n|) = O(a_n)$.

(5?) However, a book I recently read implicitly uses a result that I find dubious,

If $|{\bf A}_n| = O(1)$ and $v_n = O(1)$, then $v'_n{\bf A} v_n = O(1)$

Statement (5) seems very suspicious since for a given determinant you can have a norm arbitrarily large. However, maybe it is somehow true for (semi)-positive definite matrices?

In any case I wonder if someone compiled a list of nice results of the $O(1)$ and $o(1)$ notation for matrices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $|A_n|$ is the determinant, (5) is false even for PD matrices. Take simply
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}\frac1\varepsilon & 0\\ 0 & \varepsilon\end{bmatrix}, \quad v = \begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}.
$$

As for a list of big-O results, I don't know of one, and I think it would be too big to be remotely useful.